# XPath to extract text after br tags in R

Tags: r, xpath

How to extract text after the `br` tags in the following lines:

```
<div id='population'>
    The Snow Leopard Survival Strategy (McCarthy <em>et al.</em> 2003, Table
    II) compiled national snow leopard population estimates, updating the work
    of Fox (1994). Many of the estimates are acknowledged to be rough and out
    of date, but the total estimated population is 4,080-6,590, as follows:<br>
    <br>
    Afghanistan: 100-200?<br>
    Bhutan: 100-200?<br>
    China: 2,000-2,500<br>
    India: 200-600<br>
    Kazakhstan: 180-200<br>
    Kyrgyzstan: 150-500<br>
    Mongolia: 500-1,000<br>
    Nepal: 300-500<br>
    Pakistan: 200-420<br>
    Russia: 150-200<br>
    Tajikistan: 180-220<br>
    Uzbekistan: 20-50
</div>
```

I got as far as:

```
xpathSApply(h, '//div[@id="population"]', xmlValue)
```

but I'm stuck now...

Comment: THere is no text _within_ `<br/>` tags... Do  you mean _between_ the several tags? You might want to clarify what you want _exactly_. A first guess would be `'//div[@id="population"]/text()[preceding-sibling::br]'`

Comment: That's it! Put it as an answer and I'll check it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It helps if you realize text is a node too. All text in the div than follows `<br/>`'s can be retrieved by:

```
//div[@id="population"]/text()[preceding-sibling::br]
```

Technically, *between* `<br/>` tags would mean:

```
//div[@id="population"]/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following-sibling::br]
```

... but I guess that's not what you want at this point.