# XPath to extract text within br

Tags: xpath

```html
<div id="t_info" class="tab-pane fade active in tab">

<br><strong>Delivery</strong> <br>

<br><br><br><strong>Model Name</strong> : BP250

<br>

<br>Full HD up-scaling dramatically improves the resolution of any original content to Full HD. 
<br>
<br><strong>Barcode</strong> : 8806087225921
<br>
<br><strong>Product Type</strong> : Blu-ray Player<br>
<br>Blu-Ray Disc <br>External <br></div>
```

I need  xpath to  capture the barcode value. Location of the barcode varies  depending on the description.

I have tried //*[text()='Barcode'] . but i cant  capture the value.

Comment: This is not valid XML, so you cannot parse if with xpath

Comment: In addition to the comment by @OldProgrammer, if you want to use XPath to handle HTML documents, you need to use something like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to extract text after br tags in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252407/xpath-to-extract-text-after-br-tags-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use next XPath:

`(//div[@id="t_info"]/text())[./preceding::strong[text()='Barcode']][1]`

Please note that it is mauvais ton (bad manners)