# use xpath for extracting text after <br/> tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the next HTML. I  want to extract the name with xpath, in my case is Steve. I use Selenium Python. How can i do it?

```
<section class="PersonalCard">
  <!--<h2></h2>-->
  <div class="clr" style="height:25px"/>
   <span>Speciality:</span>
   <br/>
   Steve 
   <div class="clr" style="height:40px"/>
   <h3>Details</h3>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
     <div class="clr" style="height:40px"/>
     <div class="clr">
</section>
```

Comment: What are u try Please Provide and what exactly You want is not cleared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to extract text after br tags in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252407/xpath-to-extract-text-after-br-tags-in-r)

Comment: I want to extract the name that comes after <br/>

Answer (score 1):

You can use below way to get the text by executing javascript

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@class='PersonalCard']/div[@class='clr']")
print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[4].textContent", element).strip())
```

Comment: Still not, because i don't know Java.

Comment: Its not java bro, Its python code. You just paste these 2 line in your code where you need to get the text and let me know

Comment: Okay, i will try it

Comment: It failed in the second row. Very important to say, that sometimes the number of elements change, but the then name always will come after br tag

Comment: might be your element changing. Just replace the  correct index of text. As your posted html is not enough to debug the same

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something similar for this xpath:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="clr"]/span/br')
```

Comment: yes. i tried, but it doesn't help. FirePath doesn't see br/.

Comment: Try to find this XPath in browser

Comment: It probably happened because you haven't enough XPath path. Can you paste the link where you trying to find it?